# How to pass parameters to Python's HTMLParser __init__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, html-parsing

I am learning python and have a problem passing a parameter. According to the documentation, the `HTMLParser` class is defines as follows:

```
class html.parser.HTMLParser(strict=False, *, convert_charrefs=False)
```

In my derived class I like to pass `True` in the `convert_charrefs` parameter. How can I do that? Here is my code so far

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyParser( HTMLParser ):
    def __init(self)__:
        super(MyParser, self).__init__( ??? )
```

So, what should i write instead of ?*?*? to pass a *True* value in `convert_charrfs`?

**Update:** The obvious solution is to call `__init__(convert_charrefs=True)` I did try that, but it did not work for me because I was using python 3.3.4 instead of 3.4

Comment: `def __init__(self)` not `def __init(self)__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be

```
super(MyParser, self).__init__(convert_charrefs=True)
```

Comment: I have tried that but I get the error message: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'convert_charrefs'

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python version 3.4 or higher? The `convert_charrefs` keyword was added in 3.4.

Answer (score 2):

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyParser, self).__init__(convert_charrefs=True)
```